# Doesnot returning an select object with options populated through ajax in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Doesnot returning an select object with options populated through ajax in javascript

Below i am adding the html DOM row with the existing html table,where the html table has three columns one with name and another with select box and final one having button to save the options with the name dynamically through ajax

thus the function to create row is

```
function createTable(row){
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var row = table.insertRow(row);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = "something";
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell6.appendChild(createSelctbox());
  ...
 ..
}
```

and the ajax call to create select object with its option is

```
function createSelctbox(){
var selec = document.createElement("select");
var xmlhttp = getXMLObject();
if(xmlhttp)
{
    xmlhttp.open("POST","some.php",true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {

        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        var option;
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value=data[i].id;
            option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""+data[i].something+""));
            selec.appendChild(option);
        }   
        return selec;
        }
    }
    }
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send("display="+type);              

}
```

So is this possible to return like this

Answer (score 1):

```
We unable to add <option>xx</option> parts in select box dynamically.
Instead you can try to create full select box.
```

i.e,

```
<select>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>

if you want to add <option>3</option>, then you should make new select box with newly added item.
```

cheers.

Comment: I've tried this also but the table script is not waiting untill the ajax returns the select box dom

Answer (score 1):

I highly suspect that, the problem is with the `async` option

you could try by changing this line

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","some.php",true);
```

to

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","some.php",false);
```

Comment: No its not working. Normal javascript dom returns perfectly but when it comes to ajax its not returning... if we try to alert the return it says undefined

Comment: @user1711126 have you tried with `false`? Yep, it's expected because there is no such element when you are calling that method, so make it synchronous.

Comment: yes changed to synchronous by converting to false, but also not working. so i just loaded the option on load and accessed using onclick event..

Comment: @user1711126 could you please post `getXMLObject();`, also try to put `var selec = document.createElement("select");` within status check.

Comment: `function getXMLObject()  //XML OBJECT
{
    var xmlHttp = false;
    try
    {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        try
        {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  // For Microsoft IE 6.0+
        }
        catch (e2)
        {
            xmlHttp = false;  // No Browser accepts the XMLHTTP Object then false
        }
    }
    if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined')
    {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlHttp; 
}` this is the function to create the xmlobject();